# Does C++ accept inline virtual function while performing polymorphism?

Tags: c++

```
//header.h
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Base {
    virtual void vf();
};
struct Derived :Base {
    virtual void vf();
};
inline void Base::vf() {
    cout << "Base::vf()" << endl;
}
inline void Derived::vf() {
    cout << "Derived::vf()" << endl;
}

//source.cpp
#include"header.h"
int main() {
    Base *pb = new Derived;
    pb->vf();
}

//source2.cpp
#include"header.h"
```

It compiles and works in MSVC and g++.

But if I remove both `inline` keywords, a duplicate definition error will be caught by the linker since I include function definition twice, which will break the ODR.

Since I call the virtual function with a base pointer, it should be decided at run-time, and the compiler will ignore my inlining request, causing the duplicate error.

Do I get something wrong?

Comment: `inline` keyword nowadays is largely unrelated to inlining optimization. It's mostly about One Definition Rule, about whether the linker would ignore duplicate definitions or complain about them.

Comment: *Do I get something wrong?*  When you removed the `inline` keyword, you should also have moved the routine from the header `.h` file into the associated `.cpp` file.

Comment: By the way, it's not true that a call to a virtual function is always resolved at runtime. If the optimizer can prove that a pointer always points to an instance of a particular derived class, it can "devirtualize" the call - generate a direct call to that class' overload. Which can, as a further optimization, be inlined. Thus, in your example, the optimizer could transform `pb->vf()` to `static_cast<Dervied*>(pb)->Derived::vf()`, and then possibly inline `Derived::vf()`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is there still one copy of each vf even if I include twice in my example?

Comment: In theory, this is an implementation detail irrelevant to the programmer. The compiler and linker must arrange for this to work, somehow. In practice, a typical implementation would place a copy of the function's body in every `.obj` file generated from a translation unit that contains its definition, and then the linker would discard all but one copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code is currently written, the member functions are defined in `header.h` and marked `inline`. That's okay from the perspective of the language definition: `inline` means "it's okay to have multiple [identical] definitions of this function". From a maintenance perspective it can make things harder. In particular, when you do this, every time you change the implementation of any of those functions you have to recompile all of the source files that use that header. Putting the definitions of those functions into their own source file[s] means you only have to recompile the file[s] that changed.

If you don't want to mark your functions `inline` (and you don't want to define them inside the class definition, which makes them implicitly inline), then you have to put each function definition into exactly one source file. A useful first step is to define all of the non-inline member functions of a class in a single source file. So your `source2.cpp` might look like this (yes, that's member functions from two classes):

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

void Base::vf() {
    std::cout << "Base::vf()\n";
}

void Derived::vf() {
    std::cout << "Derived::vf()\n";
}
```

and you'd remove those definitions from `header.h`. So now `header.h` contains only the class definition; `source2.cpp` has the definitions of the member functions; and `source.cpp` has the `main` function.

Comment: I have learned that whether `inline` is accepted depends on the compiler at compile-time and virtual mechanism is a run-time decision. So I put the definition in the header file, for experiment, to see **if compiler ignoring `inline` is equivalent to removing `inline` keyword**. It seems that is not.

Comment: @sakugawa -- if you have a compiler that doesn't allow `inline` as written here, get rid of it. It's seriously flawed. This is **exactly** what `inline` is intended for.

Comment: I wonder if the `inline` keyword in modern c++ have nothing to do with expanding the code(function body) at the point where function is invoked. Is it more like allowing **multiple definition** but still one copy in program?

Comment: @sakugawa -- yes, that's right. It originally was a hint to expand the function inline, with an implication that multiple identical definitions were allowed. Compilers quickly got smarter about inlining functions. That hint became pointless, but the implication of multiple definitions being allowed in the source code stayed. If the function is expanded inline there are as many copies as there are expansions. There may also be one separate version of the function that's called normally, if that's needed.

Answer (score 2):

The One Definition Rule is mandatory. It is required by C++. A given object or a function must be defined exactly once. Removing the `inline` keyword (in your case) violates this rule, making the resulting program ill-formed.

Runtime polymorphism and virtual function dispatch happens at run time. You can only get to the run time part if your program is well-formed. If it breaks the ODR it is not well-formed, so how runtime polymorphism and virtual function dispatch works becomes a moot point. If your program is ill-formed there won't be anything to run and no base pointer at all.

It is true that an ODR violation does not require a diagnostic, but the resulting code is still broken. Please write a thank-you note to your compiler for alerting you to the problem.